# Is there a way to get value from specific <div> in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to get the values that are contained in a specific div. The HTML page contains several sections, which are activated when the corresponding button is clicked.
The problem is that having only one route function this is called only once and not every time the button is pressed to change the section.
I tried using `value = request.args.get("home")` but it returns None as soon as it loads the first section and then it doesn't return anything anymore.
Specifically I would like to get the values of the name, email, subject and message fields contained in the form.
Below I leave the code:

HTML (index.html):

```
<body class="main-content">
    <header class="container header active" id="home">
        <div class="header-content">
            <h1>Hello to everyone</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
               Eveniet labore nihil obcaecati consequatur. Debitis error doloremque,
               vero eos vel nemo eius voluptatem dicta tenetur modi.
            </p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="about">
           <div class="about-container>
              <h2>About Me</h2>
              <div class="about-container">
                 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                     Eveniet labore nihil obcaecati consequatur. Debitis error doloremque,
                     vero eos vel nemo eius voluptatem dicta tenetur modi.
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
           <div class="contact-container">
              <form method="POST" action="" class="contact-form">
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="YOUR NAME">
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="YOUR EMAIL">
                  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required placeholder="ENTER SUBJECT">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="15" rows="8" placeholder="Message Here..."></textarea>
                   <div class="submit-btn" align="center">
                      <a href="#" class="main-btn">
                          <span class="btn-text">Send email</span>
                          <span class="btn-icon"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></span>
                      </a>
                   </div>
              </form>
           </div>
        </section>
</body>
```

.py

```
@main.route("/")
def home():
   # These do not return anything
   name = request.form.get('name')
   email = request.form.get('email')
   subject = request.form.get('subject')
   message = request.form.get('message')
   return render_template('index.html')
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure? Try changing the action to `/submit` and the route to `@main.route("/submit")` and see what happens because even with `get` it should return `None` and instead of returning the template, return the values. Then make sure the route accepts `POST`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit" class="contact-form">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="YOUR NAME">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="YOUR EMAIL">
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required placeholder="ENTER SUBJECT">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="15" rows="8" placeholder="Message Here..."></textarea>
  <div class="submit-btn" align="center">
    <a href="#" class="main-btn">
      <span class="btn-text">Send email</span>
      <span class="btn-icon"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Python**

```
@main.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])
def form_submit():
   name = request.form.get('name')
   email = request.form.get('email')
   subject = request.form.get('subject')
   message = request.form.get('message')
   return name
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, but it opens a page with Method Not Allowed

Comment: Typo in my original code - please try again. Added a closing square bracket to the route

Comment: Nothing changed, I already had the square bracket